# Comparar coincidencias de palabras en textos que esten en subcarpetas e imprimir resultado

Tags: python, archivo, comparaciones, buscador, procesamiento-de-texto

Sludos a todos,
Soy nuevo en python 3, si me pueden ayudar

Tengo que comparar un listado de palabras que están en list-word en varios archivos txt que se encuentran en subcarpetas, y una vez terminado en la primera carpeta hacer el mismo proceso en las demas hasta terminar

> folderprincipal
>                 folder-01 / text1.txt ......textn.txt
>                 folder-02 / text1.txt ......textn.txt
>                 folder-03 / text1.txt ......textn.txt
>                 folder-0n / text1.txt ......textn.txt

Cita en bloque

list-word.txt   (este texto esta en otra dirección)
Esta lista puede ser Nombres por ejemplo cada ua en una línea.

```
> import sys 
>import os 
>list_words = [] list_lines = []
> 
> #sys.stdout=open("/home/sergioml/Descargas/ejerciciosphy/salida.txt", 'wt') # graba a u archivo de texto la salida.
> search_path="/home/sergioml/Descargas/ejercicios-phy/textos/"
> f1 =open('/home/sergioml/Descargas/ejercicios-phy/list.txt') #list
> palabras for line in f1.readlines():
>     # remove the trailing \n
>     list_words.append(line[:-1])   

>file_type = ("txt") 
>salida=0    
> for fname in os.listdir(path=search_path):
>     # Apply file type filter    
>     if fname.endswith(file_type):
>         f2 = open(search_path+fname) 
>         for line in f2.readlines():
>         # remove the trailing \n
>             list_lines.append(line[:-1])
>             salida += 1#numero de lineas leidas
>             for word in list_words:  #BUSCA PALABRAS RECORRE Y 
>                 if word in line:
>                     index = line.find(word)
>                     print(fname," --> ", line, sep=" ") print 
>(salida) #numero de lineas leidas restar -1
```

Actualmente creo tener el código del proceso  para leer una carpeta, pero ahi aveces lee ciertos archivos pero no imprime su coincidencia.
aqui dejo el código:

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Sergio, primero bienvenido a [es.so]. Por otro lado, ten en cuenta que buscas subcadenas no palabras propiamente dichas, es decir si tienes la palabra "Over" la línea "Ésto es StackOverflow en español" dará un positivo aunque no existe "Over" como palabra en si. Por otro lado no tienes en cuenta las mayúsculas y si una subcadena está dos veces en una linea solo tienes en cuenta la primera. No se si lo anterior lo quieres así o no, solo son observaciones. Por otro lado, ¿podrías agregar un ejemplo de linea o archivo que no encuentre y la palabra?, para generar un [mcve].

Comment: Aparte de lo anterior, el código es muy optimizable, no necesitas cargar el archivo en memoria completo y ahora lo cargas por duplicado además (por el uso de las dos listas con las líneas), además debes siempre cerrar un archivo cuando termines con él. La búsqueda por lineas se puede optimizar para evitar iterar por cada palabra a buscar usando regex por ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias FJSevilla, no habia tomado encuenta tus observaciones de si se repite el mismo nombre 2 veces en una línea, que sería bueno hacerlo, lo de cargar en memoria no lo mire y no estoy cerrando cuando leo el archivo, revisare regex cómo indicas,

Comment: Luego me toca mirar la otra parte que necesito, recorrer en todas las carpetas quee s lo que no funciona :(

Comment: Puedo crear una respuesta, no es muy complicado realmente, lo que si me gustaría saber es mi primera observación, ¿realmente quieres buscar subcadenas o palabras? La implementación cambia considerablemente. Por otro lado, ¿quieres que se ignoren las mayúsculas o no?

Comment: FJ sevilla efectivamente es tu primera observación bucar cadenas y si por ahora que se ignoren las mayúsculas, porque el objetivo es que en el archivo list.txt, pueda ir agregando a futuro en la siguiente linea Nombres y apellidos, o solo un nombre, para buscarlos en los otros textos